# Why $(A-B)\times (A-B) = A\times A - A\times B - B\times A + B\times B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I was watching a lecture on multivariable calculus online and at some point the lecturer wrote $$(A-B)\times (A-B) = A\times A - A\times B - B\times A + B\times B$$ without explaining the steps he did.

Could you tell me what are the steps/the formula to transform $(A-B)\times (A-B) = A\times A - A\times B - B\times A + B\times B$?

Comment: what is $A$, $B$?

Comment: It is just "multiplying out" with considering the signs. The formula follows from the distributive law.

Comment: Use the definition to deduce that....

Comment: Also in a non-commutative ring, $$(A-B)\times(A-B)=A\times(A-B)-B\times(A-B) = A\times A-A\times B-B\times A+B\times B$$ by the distributive property.

Comment: I wonder (given the multivariable calc context) whether $A$ and $B$ are perhaps *sets*, and the $\times$ denotes cartesian product, while the $-$ denotes set-difference. Cristian: can you tell us, please?